# lost access to my store

Tags: magento2, admin

I have changed the URL of my site from DNS and I did the change on the admin for the new site but now it seems that I lost access, cant access the site or the admin panel, any ideas?

Comment: you have to check inside database, core_config_data tabel in check your store url. Also remove cache of your store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that many times :)  if your new site is www.example.com then run the following commands from your root install directory of Magento, for instance, if its var/www/html/magento2 then go there and run

php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.example.com"
php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.example.com"
php bin/magento cache:flush

and you should be set.

Comment: Glad it helped :)